# Checking if condition is between two values and assigning dummy variables

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to check whether a certain renter is between a specified age range, and then assign it a binary variable whether it is or isn't.

I tried using a lambda function on the column specifically:

```
df['<= 18'] = df['rider_age'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x <= 18 else 0)
df['19-24'] = df['rider_age'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x <=19 & x >=24 else 0)
df['25-35'] = df['rider_age'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x <=25 & x >=35 else 0)
df['36-50'] = df['rider_age'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x <=36 & x >=50 else 0)
df['51-59'] = df['rider_age'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x <=51 & x >=59 else 0)
df['51-59'] = df['rider_age'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x <=51 & x >=59 else 0)
df['60+'] =   df['rider_age'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x >=60 else 0)
```

Now this works for those 18 and under and 60 and older, but it just marks the ages in between as 0 for the respective column that they should be marked as 1.

Anyone have any ideas on how to work this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix your code only. You have wrong conditions for those middle commands. You need `=> & <=` instead of `<= & >=`. Second thing, you need to wrap each condition in parantheses as follows

```
df['<= 18'] = df['rider_age'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x <= 18 else 0)
df['19-24'] = df['rider_age'].apply(lambda x: 1 if (x >=19) & (x <= 24) else 0)
df['25-35'] = df['rider_age'].apply(lambda x: 1 if (x >=25) & (x <= 35) else 0)
df['36-50'] = df['rider_age'].apply(lambda x: 1 if (x >=36) & (x <= 50) else 0)
df['51-59'] = df['rider_age'].apply(lambda x: 1 if (x >=51) & (x <= 59) else 0)
df['60+'] =   df['rider_age'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x >=60 else 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check with `cut` + `get_dummies`

```
s=pd.cut(df['rider_age'],[-np.Inf,18,24,35,50,59,np.Inf]).astype(str).str.get_dummies()
```

Then `concat` back

```
df=pd.concat([df,s], axis=1)
```

---

Fix your code by change the condition from & to and

```
apply(lambda x: 1 if x <=19 and x >=24 else 0)
```

Comment: Got `AttributeError` when running the first line on `pandas==0.24`

Comment: @calestini adding the astype after cut , check the update

Comment: very nice answer. Any specific difference between `join` and `concat` on this application?

Comment: @calestini I just personal like concat . join can achieve the same

Answer (score 1):

You've got some inequalities mixed up...

Look at the second case: x has to be <= 19 AND >=24. You must mean >=19 and <= 24, right?